# Does a linearly accelerated charge radiate?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, charge, acceleration, equivalence-principle

Does a linearly accelerated charge radiate? And if yes, is the electromagnetic waves emitted detectable from both its non-inertial frame and from other observing inertial frame? And If yes, doesn't this contradict with Einstein Equivalence principle?

Comment: [The radiation of a uniformly accelerated charge is beyond the horizon: a simple derivation](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0506049)

Comment: Are you asking about linear acceleration with arbitrary time dependence? Or uniform acceleration?

Comment: @G.Smith: The mention of EEP makes me certain that OP is interested in constant acceleration.

Comment: Then the OP should say so. The question is unclear because linear acceleration has nothing to do with the Equivalence Principle.

Answer (score 2):

> Does [a] linearly accelerated charge radiate?

"It depends". Accelerating relative to whom?

> Is the electromagnetic waves emitted detectable from both its
> non-inertial frame and from other observing inertial frame

No.

> Doesn't this contradict with Einstein Equivalence principle

This is indeed an apparent paradox in GR.

---

The solution to the paradox is to accept and acknowledge that radiation has no absolute meaning. Which is the reason of the "it depends" to the first question. The emission and detection of radiation depends both on the motion of the source (radiation field) and on that of the observer.

An inertial observer, stationary with respect to the accelerating charge, will indeed detect the radiation.

But a comoving observer, to whom the charge is at rest, will *not* detect any radiation. Simple reason being that yes, in their frame the charge is not accelerating. The mathematical reason is that, when you put this in Rindler coordinates, the charge and its field are enclosed in a horizon.

Comment: Are you talking about uniform acceleration? Linear acceleration includes 1D simple harmonic motion, which certainly radiates.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes uniform acceleration, like a graviational field.

Comment: OK, but the OP didn’t ask about that. They may have intended to, though.

Comment: @G.Smith Ok sorry, it seemed to me they were asking about the typical paradox of whether a free-falling charge emits radiation as seen by a free-falling observer.

Comment: I suspect you’re right. I suggest editing your answer to say that you are assuming uniform acceleration.

Comment: I am confused by what you are saying because your answer seems to imply that a linear antenna cannot radiate. Are you saying that there is a reference frame in which AM630 does *not* radiate? What would its 100kW amplifier do when I am observing it?

Comment: @hyportnex Of course it radiates. In its own frame. If you look at the Poynting vector as you smoothly transfrom from the static to the Rindler coordinates of the accelerating observer, it vanishes.

Comment: So does this mean that in Rindler coordinates the 100kW amplifier stops working and if it is still working what will it do with its 100kW?

Comment: I think the 100 kW amplifier pertains to the rest frame of the accelerating radiation source. In that frame, it "works" as you expect. As to what another accelerating observer, they are comoving with with the other frame but not in the same rest frame. I don't know what they see the amplifier doing, but I would not necessarily expect the same thing as the guy in the amplifier's rest frame. But this is probably the end of my understanding. Sorry.

Comment: @SuperCiocia: *Of course it radiates. In its own frame.* This is wrong viewpoint. Whether an isolated system radiates is not a frame dependent but a global notion, calculable via the energy flux at future null infinity.

Comment: @A.V.S. My understanding of this paradox is that you cannot do global considerations. It's relative to the emitter and the receiver. Who sees what then depends on the relative speed between the two observers.

Comment: If the radiation in the inertial frame triggers a bomb, how an observer comoving with the charge explains the explosion of the bomb if there was not radiation to trigger it?

Comment: That's an excellent question, and I don't know the answer.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny, that's a very good question and I would suggest going through the paper posted in the earlier comment section. The radiation is in the region that is beyond the Rindler horizon for the co-moving observer and hence any effect the radiation may produce will not be known to the comoving observer.

Comment: @RohitC but assume the comoving observer (far from the charge)  just passes next to the bomb when it explodes. I will read the article.

Comment: @SuperCiocia: Once again, separation of EM field into bound part and radiation is a global and frame independent thing. Radiation fields decay as $1/r$ with distance from the source.

Comment: I really meant a linear acceleration whether it is uniform or not. Does the answer differ? and this question is the other face of another question which @SuperCiocia referred to. If ration relative to the co-acceleration observer, in my question, would not measure radiation as it is enclosed in a horizon, what about the other case?! For sure the co-free-falling observer in the other experiment should not measure any radiation! So, how should the earth observer measure a radiation? ! Actually, I am not a physicist but the intuition says that either both detect or both not.

Comment: Why wouldn't be the case as following: If the charge is on a geodetic line in the space-time, it shouldn't radiate for all observers, and if it is not, it should radiate for all observer. The difference in observation would be in the magnitude and/or frequency, or merely frequency, of the radiation.